# Oscilation inside an electric field (polar molecule)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, oscillators

Find the period of the oscilation inside an electric field with magnitude $E=3\times 10^4$V/m of a polar molecule with lenght of $1\times 10^{-8}$cm. We know that the charges $+q,-q$ are $15.7\times 10^{-20}$C each.

I don't know how to start, any hint or solution please?

Comment: Hint: What force act on a dipole in an uniform electric field? Calculate this, and try to connect the dots, and you'll get the answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @sbp I've tried to follow that way using the tork, but I don't know the aceleration, could you give me more clues? Really I feel that my brain explode!!!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all assume your molecule can be approximate by a dipole $\vec{p}$.  Then we know that $U=-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{E}$ and you can get the value of the torque applied by the field on the dipole about its center is: 
$$\vec{\tau}=\vec{p} \times \vec{E} $$

Now assume that the molecule has a moment of inertia $I$, this depends on what molecule you are analysing. You can use the rigid body relation: 
$$\tau=I\ddot{\theta}$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{p}$ and $\hat{y}$. Equating the two equation you get:

$$I\ddot{\theta}=pE\sin(\theta)\approx pE\theta$$

Which it holds for small angle deviation around the equilibrium (i.e. the dipole being parallel to the field). From that differential equation you can get the frequency of oscillation.